# Rails—foreign key loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models, `project` and `single_object_interactive`

```
class SingleObjectInteractive < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :single_object_interactive
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :single_object_interactive
end
```

When I try to create a `project`, I get an error that its `single_object_interactive` doesn't have a `project`.

This following code works:

```
def create
  @project = Project.new(project_params)
  @project.single_object_interactive.project = @project
  @project.save
```

It works, but it feels broken and loopy. Why doesn't the project's `single_object_interactive` automatically link to the project?

#### update

Here's the error message if I call `@project.save!` without the weird `@project.single_object_interactive.project = @project` line:

```
(0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
*** ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid Exception: Validation failed: Single object interactive project must exist

nil
```

Comment: Why exactly are you doing this? `@project.single_object_interactive.project = @project`. I'm pretty sure if you're passing the nested array through your form then you don't need this line at all. Also if you're submitting from the view of model SingleObjectInteractive, the project_id can be linked easily to it in it's controller's create method.

Comment: Can you please give us details of the actual error that you observe when you don't have the code that "works"? That will help us to pinpoint the actual source of the problem so you don't have to do it that way. Also if we could see the details of your form-fields that might also help :)

Comment: Updated with the error message, it's within `projects_controller.rb`. The problem is that `@project.single_objective_interactive.project == nil`

Comment: Whats in `project_params`